# Disable the lync option menu in lync client

Tags: c#, lync, lync-client-sdk

Is there a way to disable lync options in lync client using lync sdk?

I have looked at this third party product [PolicyPak](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCEQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.policypak.com%2Fproducts%2Fmange-microsoft-lync-client-using-group-policy.html&ei=l3EvVb_QFJb5aqnjgPAL&usg=AFQjCNGmCgF5GzKzJTQXLKAiGpKkR3x_wg&sig2=AqDN4aSIkKnmhQq6yDNQ5Q&bvm=bv.91071109,d.ZWU).

How can I achieve this with `C#` code?

Comment: Attempt to fix grammer and clarify question, assumed language implied by "code" was c# due to tag, changed to reference this for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to disable any option in the Lync Client using the Lync Client SDK.

You are better looking at the [Group Policies](https://technet.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/gg425941%28v=ocs.15%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and [Client Experience options](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn954919%28v=ocs.15%29.aspx) supported by the Lync Client.